# bind child user control to class property

Tags: wpf

I have a usercotrol called BookControl. I added the usercontrol as a child to a window called MainWindow. I would like to bind the child control to a property in the MainViewModel.

I'm using mvvm light.
Thanks.

Here is my code:

MainWindow

```
    <Window 
     DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=Main}">
 <Controls:BookControl DataContext="{Binding Path=bookviewmodel}" ></Controls:BookControl>
```

### MainViewModel

```
    public BookViewModel bookviewmodel { get; set; }
  public MainViewModel()
    {
        bookviewmodel = new BookViewModel();

    }
```

### BookViewModel

```
  public BookModel Book { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the MainViewModel class.
    /// </summary>

    public BookViewModel()
    {
        Book = new BookModel{Title = "A Book", Author = "Some Author", Description = "Its a really good book!"};
    }
```

BookControl

```
<UserControl>
<Grid>
 <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Title}"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Author}"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Description}"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="3" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" Content="Save" />
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: So now by doing the above you are binding it to a property in MainWidow.

Comment: but it is not working, i cant see the data in the mainwindow

Comment: keep break point for your `bookviewmodel` and check its hitting the `get`. if not then change your property like this 
` private BookViewModel _BookViewModel ;
public BookViewModel BookViewModel 
        {
            get { return _BookViewModel ; }
            set { _BookViewModel  = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
        }`
Then try keeping the break point and check if it hits the `get`

Comment: check your binding for `Book` in your `BookControl`. post your `BookControl.XAML` code

Comment: Thanks Abin, your solution was the right one :)

Comment: have posted as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating your ViewModel property like below,

```
private BookViewModel _BookViewModel ; 
public BookViewModel BookViewModel 
 { 
   get { return _BookViewModel ; } 
   set { 
          _BookViewModel = value; 
          NotifyPropertyChanged(); 
       } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make you property a dependency property or use INotifyPropertyChanged.